# Continue Script with Matplotlib Figure Open

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib figure that is updated in a loop. I want the window to remain open at the end of the loop and the script to continue.

Here is a little example:

```
import tkinter
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('TKAgg', force=True)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

def main():
  showFigure()
  print("This is printed before the figure is closed.")

def showFigure():
  x, y = [], []
  plt.ion()
  fig = plt.figure()

  for i in range(0, 100):
    x.append(i)
    y.append(random.randint(0, 10))
    plt.plot(x, y, 'r-')

    fig.canvas.draw()
    fig.canvas.flush_events()
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

In that example, I want at the end of the loop the window to remain open and "This is printed before the figure is closed." to be printed [Meaning that the script did indeed continue].

I have already try to had a plt.show() at the end of the showFigure() Function with the block Option, but it did not do what I want.

- with `plt.show(block=True)`: The Figure remains open but the script will continue only if I close the window.
- with `plt.show(block=False)`: The Figure closes automatically at the end of the loop. Same thing with
  `plt.show()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, simply adding `plt.show(block=True)` at the end of the `main` function should do the job.

```py
# [...] 

def main():
  showFigure()
  print("This is printed before the figure is closed.")
  plt.show(block=True)

# [...]
```

The figure shows, updates, and stays on screen - then the `print` instruction is executed and the script remains running (waiting) while the matplotlib figure is not closed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
However, even if that works for this example, in the script I'm writing, It's not only a print that need to be executed at the same time the figure is open. So, this won't work. 
And I would prefer to show the plot and then execute the rest of the script. Not this opposite.

Comment: This code "show the plot and then execute the rest of the script".  I let you try but as you're using `plt.ion()` in `showFigure()`, it will display the figure (with updates), then continue to the print (figure still displayed), then wait for the image to be closed.